# Troubles with ForeignKey in Django

Tags: python, django

I have models like this:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, ...)

class Curriculum(models.Model):
    name = models.IntegerField(unique=True, ...)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)

class Grade(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,...)
    curriculum = models.ForeignKey(Curriculum, ...)
```

If I know name of specific instance of Grade, how I can get list of Subjects, which linked with Grade through Curriculum. I've tried something like the following:

```
curriculum = Grade(name=grade).curriculum
subjectsqueryset = curriculum.subjects
```

but received an exception

> `django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`: Grade has no curriculum.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Grade` object with known name in your database. Then you can filter using:

```
obj = Grade.objects.get(name=grade)
# access curriculum
obj.curriculum
# get subjects
obj.curriculum.subjects.all()
```

What you where doing is create an instance of `Grade` with `name=grade`. But this is not in the db yet and you didn't set the `curriculum` attribute. That's why you got the `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access your existing `Grade` with this line:

```
curriculum = Grade(name=grade).curriculum
```

You are creating a new `Grade`-object having `name` the value of `grade`. This is not what you want.

Use

```
my_grade = Grade.objects.get(name=grade)
my_grade.curriculum # or whatever ...
```

to work with an existing object.

If you want to create an new object you have to save it before accessing any related objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
grade = Grade.objects.get(id=id) # grade instance
curriculum = grade.curriculum # curriculum is a Foreign Key
subjects = curriculum.subjects.all() # subjects is a ManyToManyField
for subject in subjects:
    print subject # each subject of curriculum
```